# How to declare type of new column in select statement?

Tags: postgresql

How to declare type of new column in select statement. I have made output of division of two select statement but it return 0 value. It's probably because it's automatically declare column as a bigint. I would like to change it to numeric in query so I can see float number. How can I do that?

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM public."bbb"
WHERE "aaa" IN (    SELECT "aaa"
                        FROM public."ccc"
                        WHERE "Stream" = 'A')
AND "quantity" > 1) /


(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM public."bbb"
WHERE "aaa" IN (    SELECT "aaa"
                        FROM public."ccc"
                        WHERE "Stream" = 'A')) as result
```

Comment: `count(*)::numeric`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing *integer division*. Use a type cast. Either in the standard conforming syntax

```
CAST (expression AS double precision)
```

or in the shorter PostgreSQL slang

```
expression::double precision
```